# Different answer from using definition of contour integral to using Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

The contour integral is:
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\cos z + i \sin z}{(z^2 + 36)(z+2)} \mathrm{d} z$$
where $\Gamma$ is the circle centred at the origin, with radius 3, traversed once positively.

I computed this contour integral to be $\frac{\pi i e^{-2}}{20}$, however, WolframAlpha is claiming that it's equal to zero when I try to do it by parametrisation with $z:= e^{it}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.
W|A Link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+2pi+of+(e%5E(i(e%5E(it)))%2F((e%5E(2it)+%2B+36)(e%5E(it)%2B2))+*++e%5E(it)+*+i+dt

Why does W|A give a different answer? Am I wrong then with my original answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You gave Wolfram Alpha the wrong integral to do.  Your parametrization was $z = e^{it}$, but this gives a circle of radius $1$, not a circle of radius $3$.
With the correct parametrization $z = 3 e^{it}$, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%200%20to%202pi%20of%20(e%5E(i(3%20e%5E(it)))%2F((9%20e%5E(2it)%20%2B%2036)(3%20e%5E(it)%2B2))%20%203%20e%5E(it)%20%20i%20dt) gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+36}$. Then, by the integral formula:

$$\int_\Gamma\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+2)(z^2+36)}\,dz=\int_\Gamma\frac{f(z)}{z+2}\,dz= 2 \pi i f(-2)=\frac{\pi i e^{-2i}}{20}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is
$$\int_\Gamma\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+2)(z^2+36)}\,dz.$$
The only pole inside $\Gamma$ is at $z=-2$ and is simple. The residue
is
$$\frac{e^{-2i}}{40}$$
so the integral is
$$\frac{\pi i e^{-2i}}{20}.$$

As for why Wolfie A gives zero, that I suspect will be forever a mystery.